# What is the function of state in a pseudorandom number generator?

Tags: algorithm, security, cryptography

I'm working on a pseudorandom number generator for an assignment and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how state is used in it. What does it mean to advance to the next one? I'm not looking for tips on implementation, just an explanation of the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A PRNG generates a *sequence* of numbers.

To calculate the *next* number, you have some internal state (variables set to specific values, if you will). That's the *state* referred to in the context of PRNG. This state can often be represented by just a single number.

Comment: thank you! would the value of the state change with each number generated?

Comment: Small correction: usually the state is of a fixed size, containing bytes. Those bytes are generally not used as a number in e.g. hash based PRNGs.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: hence, *representable* by a single number :) Old-school bit scrambling shift registers, for example, are PRNG, and if you just concatenate all the currently set bits into a sequence, you get a number :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for the clarifying edit!